# Automata that respect the condition {w|w contains at least two 0s and at most one 1}

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

we have the alphabet {0,1}.

{w|w contains at least two 0s and at most one 1}

It tried this: (However I'm not sure if it's correct. If it's incorrect why?)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously not correct, as every state is an accepting state - meaning this will accept literally *every word* (not to mention you forgot to define what B does when it sees a '1').

Although, even if we would have changed state A to be non-accepting, then this dfa would have accepted words with exactly one 1's (and any amount of 0's)

To fix this, we must do the following changes:

1. make A a non-accepting state.
2. add a state C that A will point to when it gets a '0' and D will go to B when it sees a '0'
3. create three more states D, E, F that will act like copies of A, D, B - **BUT** will will send to C on a 1, and we will have A,D send to E,F respectively on 1.
4. add state C that is non-accepting, where F will send you to it when it sees '1'. C will have a connection to itself for both 0 and 1. this state is usually referred as a *terminating state*, as there is no way out and it is not accepting.

The new DFA looks like this:[image]

I have tried to make it look such that every 'row' counts the number of 1's and columns count the number of 0's

Comment: why is it necessary to tell how B will behave with 1 if we don't do it with C for example. I assume because it's an accepting state, right?

Comment: it is neccecary as it is in the definition of a DFA. thank you for letting me know i forgot to add transtions! i will update this soon